# How can a system be in superposition when there’s a force associated with it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, double-slit-experiment, superposition, wavefunction-collapse

Not sure what the best way to word the title would be but I’ll explain further: suppose we’re talking about the double slit experiment. As the electron moves its electric field changes, which exerts a force on all nearby charges. Solely from Coulomb’s law/the associated potential (which is where I’m assuming more nuance comes in) this force should affected all of space. Under this assumption, how could indeterminacy be feasible? Doesnt the interaction undergone by other particles with this force constitute a measurement, therefore causing the wavefunction to collapse? I don’t care if the force is “negligible”, from the equations we still be to assuming to be true (Coulombs law) it should still have a quantifiable interaction with other charged particles, which includes the atoms constituting the observer and, well, everything.

Overall I don’t see how superposition can work when a particle/quantum system is exerting forces/causing interactions with other particles that depend on its exact location.

Im assuming the error in my logic boils down to how I’m modeling forces. I’m still in the process of learning the basics but I feel like just from information I’ve gathered in the past there’s no indication forces/potentials get reworked. Assuming my point isn’t completely wrong, does this idea eventually get reconciled? I’ve heard for example that the EM field is mediated by photons and in this case I guess I’d say superposition could work, especially due to the fact that this (might?) mean the force doesn’t actually affect all of space, but so far in the QM formulation I’m not convinced that forces/potentials which rely on an explicit physical quantity work with superposition.

Comment: How comfortable are you with the mathematical side of quantum mechanics? Specifically the Schrödinger equation?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos I’ve began to learn it but I don’t see how the math fixes/could fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> I’m still in the process of learning the basics but I feel like just from information I’ve gathered in the past there’s no indication forces/potentials get reworked.

And that's precisely where the error lies. In classical mechanics, the time evolution of a system is fundamentally determined by Newton's laws, most prominently $F=ma$, which is a differential equation determining the position of a particle. That's how forces act in classical mechanics. In quantum mechanics, the time evolution of a system is not determined by this equation, so forces must act differently. Quantum mechanics has the Schrödinger equation as the determining factor of time evolution, and the equation works using potentials instead of forces. Specifically, for an $n$-particle system, the equation is

$$\mathrm i\hbar\partial_t\Psi(x_1,\dots,x_n,t)=-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_i}\Delta_n\Psi(x_1,\dots,x_n,t)~+~V(x_1,\dots,x_n)\Psi(x_1,\dots,x_n,t),$$

Where $x_i$ are the position coordinates of each particle, $m_i$ are their masses, $\Delta_n$ is the Laplace operator with respect to the coordinates of the $i$-th particle and $V$ is the potential energy of the system when the particles are at the specified positions. For two electrons, this looks like the following:

$$\mathrm i\hbar\partial_t\Psi=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_e}(\Delta_1+\Delta_2)\Psi+\frac{e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0\vert x_2-x_1\vert}\Psi.$$

Where measurements are concerned, this equation says: How the probability to find the two electrons in the configuration $x_1,x_2$ changes in time ($\mathrm i\hbar\partial_t\Psi$) is influenced by the probability to find the electrons in a similar but different configuration ($-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_e}(\Delta_1+\Delta_2)\Psi$) and the potential energy they would have in the given configuration ($\frac{e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0\vert x_2-x_1\vert}\Psi$). There is no issue with undetermined position here. All possible positions are incorporated into the dynamics.

*Note*: When I say that the changes in probability are influenced by something, I mean influenced, not determined. The same probability distribution can have different dynamics if the underlying wave function $\Psi$ has some arbitrary position-dependent phase factor. $\mathrm i\hbar\partial_t\Psi$ describes the change of the wave function, which in turn determines the probability distribution.

As for the wave function collapsing: The two particles are not macroscopic, so their interaction won't cause a collapse. They simply follow the dynamics decreed by the Schrödinger equation.

Comment: Ah so in this case the potential isn’t really an artifact of the system and its exact physical quantities (position), it’s better to think of it like an operator? (I know it’s actually an operator in the Schrödinger equation but that’s not what I mean—I mean do we consider the potential as something physical?) In other words, in classical mechanics we consider the potential around a charge being determined by the charges position, in classical mechanics do we abandon this idea?

Comment: The potential is still determined by a charge's position in some sense. But not every physical state has one specific potential energy, just as not every physical state has one specific position configuration. A state with fixed positions (a position eigenstate) will also have a fixed potential, though (it is a potential energy eigenstate).

Comment: I think I understand now, it’s (kind of) like the potential is in a superposition itself and affects each possible state of the particle it’s interacting with accordingly with the probability of each position it can take? And by having the wavefunction describe both particles it can make this notion actually well defined so that the particle it’s interacting with can take into account the fact that it doesn’t have a definite potential?

Comment: Yes, I think you got the gist.